# "Зона видимости" (туман войны) в Qt

Tags: qt

Необходимо сделать так называемую "зону видимости" (туман войны) вокруг объекта (в моем случае - это объект, который ходит по лабиринту), чтобы объект видел, к примеру, только клетки вокруг себя. Лабиринт - таблица QTableWidget, объект - QPixmap. Подскажите или дайте наводку, как это можно сделать.

Answer (score 2):

Можно сделать через свою модель+делегат. Например:
**testtablemodel.h**

```
#pragma once

#include <QAbstractTableModel>

class TestTableModel : public QAbstractTableModel
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:

    enum Roles {
        CURRENT = Qt::UserRole,
        VISIBLE
    };
    explicit TestTableModel(QObject *parent = nullptr);

    QVariant headerData(int section, Qt::Orientation orientation, int role = Qt::DisplayRole) const override;

    int rowCount(const QModelIndex &parent = QModelIndex()) const override;
    int columnCount(const QModelIndex &parent = QModelIndex()) const override;

    QVariant data(const QModelIndex &index, int role = Qt::DisplayRole) const override;

public slots:
    void setCurrent(const QModelIndex& value, const QModelIndex &prevision);

private:
    bool isVisible(const QModelIndex& index) const;

private:
    QModelIndex current;

};
```

**testtablemodel.cpp**

```
#include "testtablemodel.h"
#include <math.h>

const auto MAX_WAY = 3;

TestTableModel::TestTableModel(QObject *parent)
    : QAbstractTableModel(parent) {}

QVariant TestTableModel::headerData(int section, Qt::Orientation orientation, int role) const {
    if(role == Qt::DisplayRole) return section;
    return {};
}

int TestTableModel::rowCount(const QModelIndex &parent) const    {
    if (parent.isValid()) return 0;
    return 100;
}

int TestTableModel::columnCount(const QModelIndex &parent) const    {
    if (parent.isValid()) return 0;
    return 100;
}

QVariant TestTableModel::data(const QModelIndex &index, int role) const
{
    if (!index.isValid()) return QVariant();

    if(role == Qt::DisplayRole) if(index == current) return "X";
    if(role == Roles::CURRENT) return current;
    if(role == Roles::VISIBLE) return isVisible(index);

    return QVariant();
}

void TestTableModel::setCurrent(const QModelIndex& value, const QModelIndex &prevision)    {
    if(!value.isValid()) return;
    current = value;

    emit dataChanged(index(prevision.row()-MAX_WAY, prevision.column()-MAX_WAY),
                     index(prevision.row()+MAX_WAY, prevision.column()+MAX_WAY));

    emit dataChanged(index(current.row()-MAX_WAY, current.column()-MAX_WAY),
                     index(current.row()+MAX_WAY, current.column()+MAX_WAY));

}

bool TestTableModel::isVisible(const QModelIndex& index) const    {
    if(!index.isValid()) return false;

    auto way = std::sqrt(std::pow(index.row()-current.row(),2)
                         + std::pow(index.column()-current.column(),2));

    return MAX_WAY > way;
}
```

**styleditemdelegate.h**

```
#pragma once

#include <QStyledItemDelegate>
#include <QObject>

class CustomItemDelegate : public QStyledItemDelegate
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit CustomItemDelegate(QObject *parent = nullptr);

    void paint(QPainter *painter, const QStyleOptionViewItem &option,
               const QModelIndex &index) const override;
};
```

**styleditemdelegate.cpp**

```
#include "styleditemdelegate.h"
#include "testtablemodel.h"

#include <QPainter>
#include <QStyleOptionViewItem>

CustomItemDelegate::CustomItemDelegate(QObject *parent)
    : QStyledItemDelegate(parent) {}


void CustomItemDelegate::paint(QPainter *painter, const QStyleOptionViewItem &option,
                         const QModelIndex &index) const    {
    QStyleOptionViewItem no(option);
    initStyleOption(&no, index);

    QStyledItemDelegate::paint(painter, no, index);

    if(!index.data(TestTableModel::VISIBLE).toBool()) {
        painter->fillRect(option.rect, QColor("black"));
    }

}
```

Использование:

```
auto model = new TestTableModel(this);
auto table = ui->tableView;

table->setModel(model);
table->horizontalHeader()->setSectionResizeMode(QHeaderView::Stretch);
table->verticalHeader()->setSectionResizeMode(QHeaderView::Stretch);

table->setItemDelegate(new CustomItemDelegate(this));

connect(table->selectionModel(), &QItemSelectionModel::currentChanged,
        model, &TestTableModel::setCurrent);
```

Вместо pixmap тут выводится просто "X", но можно поставить pixmap также через роль. 
Делегат просто скрывает невидимые клетки, закрашивая их одним цветом.
Соответственно в модель можно добавить логику заполнения элементов лабиринта и  в зависимости от неё учитывать логику ходов.